# Change Marker image size with respect to zooming

Tags: android, google-maps

i used a image from resource as markers. but for any zooming option it shows it's actual size. How to change it with respect to zoom.

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(7.2964, 80.6350)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.hitad)));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ground overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay).

From the [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) documentation:

> Flat or Billboard orientation:
>
> By default, markers are oriented against
> the screen, and will not rotate or tilt with the camera. Flat markers
> are oriented against the surface of the earth, and will rotate and
> tilt with the camera. Both types of markers do not change size based
> on zoom. Use GroundOverlays if you desire this effect.